# Pasar variable a una vista laravel desde controlador

Tags: laravel, variables

Busco pasar una variable desde un controlador a una vista pero me arroja un error, mi controler en la funcion store redirige a una vista donde quiero mandar a llamar una variable.

Mi OrdenservicioController

```
    public function store(Request $request){

    $no_orden=$request->input('no_orden');

    $ordenservicio=new OrdenServicio;
    $ordenservicio->no_orden=$request->get('no_orden');
    $ordenservicio->RFC=$request->get('RFC');
    $ordenservicio->vehiculo=$request->get('vehiculo'); 
    $ordenservicio->mecanico=$request->get('mecanico');

    $ordenservicio->fecha_entrega=$request->get('fecha_entrega');
    $ordenservicio->hora_entrega=$request->get('hora_entrega');
    $ordenservicio->km_recorridos=$request->get('km_recorridos');
    //$ordenservicio->updated_at=$request->get('updated_at'); 
    //$ordenservicio->created_at=$request->get('created_at');
    $date=new \DateTime(); //Obtener fecha del sistema 
    //$clienteveh->fecha=$date->format('Y-m-d');
    $ordenservicio->hora_ingreso=$date->format('H:i:s');
    $ordenservicio->fecha_ingreso=$date->format('Y-m-d');
    $ordenservicio->save(); 
    return redirect('catalogocomponente.index')->with('no_orden',$no_orden);
    //$idorden=OrdenServicio::findOrFail($request->get('RFC')); 
    //return Redirect::to("catalogocomponente",["idorden"=>$idorden]);
}
```

Un input del que quiero halar un valor en la vista OrdendeServicio:

```
<input type="text" name="no_orden" id="no_orden" class="form-control">
```

Aquí mi llamada de la variable en otra vista Catalogocomponente.index

```
<input type="text" name="no_orden" value="{{$no_orden}}" class="form-control">
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error?

Comment: Tendrias que hacer un `find` a este ultimo registro que se agrego para pasarlo a la vista, porque solo lo que haces es guardarlo, puedes usar la clausula `lastInserted`

Comment: el error es que no encuentra la variable no_orden en la vista CatalogoComponente.index

Answer (score 1):

Agrega el helper route a tu instrucción redirect :

```
return redirect()->route('catalogocomponente.index')->with('no_orden',$no_orden);
```

Con el método with() lo que estas haciendo es enviar unos datos de sesión flash, es por eso que no puedes mostrar el dato en la vista como si fuera una variable, para mas información te dejo la documentación oficial de laravel donde explica a detalle todo eso https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Para mostrar el valor en la vista Catalogocomponente.index, tienes que agregar el siguiente código :

```
@if(session('no_orden'))
    <input type="text" name="no_orden" value="{{session('no_orden')}}" class="form-control">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Para **redireccionar** una una determinada página **desde el controlador Laravel**, [con el nombre de la ruta](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes):

```
return redirect()
    ->route('catalogocomponente.index')
    ->with('no_orden', $no_orden);
```

Ya en la vista para evitar errores, si la variable no llegara:

```
<input type="text"
    name="no_orden" 
    value="{{ $no_orden ?? '' }}" 
    class="form-control">
```

Por supuesto, aunque usar esta característica de PHP, u [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php), evita que la página termine en error 500, tendrás que revisar porque la variable no llega.